# Is it possible to choose multiple rows using iterrows in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

**Question**
Is it possible to choose multiple rows using iterrows with Pandas DataFrame?

**Issue**
NOW: using normal loop, it is slow.
FURTHER: want to use iterrows but not mentioned on official documents and not sure it is really possible.
(https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)

**Situation**
Currently, I am using a normal loop function for choosing multiple rows.
Below code is choosing the number of rows based on the value of the windows.

```
#NORMAL LOOP CODE
windows = 5
for i in range(len(test)):
    index_from  = test.index[i-windows+1]
    index_to = test.index[i] # Present day
    choose_db = test.loc[index_from:index_to,['Close','Vol']]
    print(choose_db)
```

It is slow when I try to run many numbers of rows.
So, I tried to use iterrows in this case.

If I run below code using the iterrows, it retrives the Series values of the chuck of rows.
I think it is the way of running the iterrows. I tried to check the official documents and other cases, but it seems not possible to choose multiple rows using it.

```
for index,row in test.iterrows():
    print(row)
```

Is it possible to choose multiple rows using iterrows?

Thank you.

Comment: What is it that you exactly want to do by selecting multiple rows? Maybe that would help in understanding it better.

Comment: I don't see what was wrong with this question. I need to batch process data in a pandas dataframe in multiple batches, and was just wondering the same thing myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, your DataFrame is something like stock market data,
something like:

```
              Open   Close   Vol
Date                            
2020-06-01  140.05  142.16  1570
2020-06-02  142.10  146.42  1800
2020-06-03  146.20  148.91  3540
2020-06-04  149.00  147.35  4573
2020-06-05  147.25  145.50  2512
2020-06-08  145.41  143.84  3663
2020-06-09  143.85  142.00  4873
2020-06-10  142.35  140.00  1570
```

It is possible to access a "window" of rows, also in a loop based on *iterrows*.

Start from:

- definig the window size (assume 3 previous days + the current one),
- copying the index to *startDate* column,
- shifting *startDate* by *winSize* positions, but in order to avoid
  *NaN* values, fill them with the starting date.

The code to do it is:

```
winSize = 3
test['startDate'] = test.index
test.startDate = test.startDate.shift(winSize, fill_value=test.index.min())
```

Then you can process (e.g. print) consecutive "windows":

```
for ind, row in test.iterrows():
    print(f'From: {row.startDate} to: {ind}')
    print(test.loc[row.startDate : ind, ['Close', 'Vol']])
    print()
```

The result is:

```
From: 2020-06-01 00:00:00 to: 2020-06-01 00:00:00
             Close   Vol
Date                    
2020-06-01  142.16  1570

From: 2020-06-01 00:00:00 to: 2020-06-02 00:00:00
             Close   Vol
Date                    
2020-06-01  142.16  1570
2020-06-02  146.42  1800

From: 2020-06-01 00:00:00 to: 2020-06-03 00:00:00
             Close   Vol
Date                    
2020-06-01  142.16  1570
2020-06-02  146.42  1800
2020-06-03  148.91  3540

From: 2020-06-01 00:00:00 to: 2020-06-04 00:00:00
             Close   Vol
Date                    
2020-06-01  142.16  1570
2020-06-02  146.42  1800
2020-06-03  148.91  3540
2020-06-04  147.35  4573

From: 2020-06-02 00:00:00 to: 2020-06-05 00:00:00
             Close   Vol
Date                    
2020-06-02  146.42  1800
2020-06-03  148.91  3540
2020-06-04  147.35  4573
2020-06-05  145.50  2512

From: 2020-06-03 00:00:00 to: 2020-06-08 00:00:00
             Close   Vol
Date                    
2020-06-03  148.91  3540
2020-06-04  147.35  4573
2020-06-05  145.50  2512
2020-06-08  143.84  3663

From: 2020-06-04 00:00:00 to: 2020-06-09 00:00:00
             Close   Vol
Date                    
2020-06-04  147.35  4573
2020-06-05  145.50  2512
2020-06-08  143.84  3663
2020-06-09  142.00  4873

From: 2020-06-05 00:00:00 to: 2020-06-10 00:00:00
             Close   Vol
Date                    
2020-06-05  145.50  2512
2020-06-08  143.84  3663
2020-06-09  142.00  4873
2020-06-10  140.00  1570
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, that is what tried. So, I can use _loc_ under _iterrows_.